# Xcode Failed to load info.plist from bundle Carthage GoogleAppMeasurement

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, simulator, carthage

So as 9 other questions here i get this error:

> Could not install at this time.
>   Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/vollan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E47CB57D-1AE7-460B-9D31-5ADE99E70A02/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.YGXslm/extracted/project.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework; Extra info about plist: ACL=

I have checked all the other 9 questions and the answers, and none of them solves it for me.

I have implemented it through Carthage and all the frameworks tend to have a header file inside of them, however, this one doesn't for some reason.

This is my carthage file:

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseRemoteConfigBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseProtobufBinary.json"
```

Comment: I feel your pain. Currently in the same hole. Have you found a solution yet? The only thing that gets me closer is this: https://medium.com/@bgtspen/firebase-crashlytics-carthage-fc4753d827cf but then it fails when i try to export an archive. Good luck!

Comment: @VijaySharma My problem was that i added all the firebase frameworks to build phase, but as they were static it shouldn't be added overthere

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Firebase frameworks from the Carthage `copy-frameworks` build phase.

More details in the instructions at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5562